# How do I get a reference to the layout of the specific row I was touching?

Tags: android, android-listview

I've created a custom adapter. Now, I would like to fade out a specific row layout when the user clicks the "cancel" button. The problem is I get only the last row created to fade out and not the row I was actually pressing in:

```
public class SwipeableRequestsAdapter extends SwipeAdapter {

    private final Context ctx;
    private final Followers[] values;
    private final Typeface roboto;
    private ImageView check;
    private ImageView cancel;
    private SwipeLayout swipeLayout;

    public SwipeableRequestsAdapter(Context context, Followers[] items) {
        ctx = context;
        values = items;
        roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "roboto_thin.ttf");

    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
        return R.id.swipe;
    }

    @Override
    public View generateView(int i, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void fillValues(int i, View view) {

        swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SwipeLayout.SwipeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClose(SwipeLayout swipeLayout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(SwipeLayout swipeLayout, int i, int i2) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen(SwipeLayout swipeLayout) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout swipeLayout, float v, float v2) {

            }
        });

        TextView requestText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sender);
        requestText.setTypeface(roboto);

        TextView requestPhone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
        requestPhone.setTypeface(roboto);
        requestPhone.setText(values[i].getNumber_sender());

        TextView currentState = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.currentState);
        currentState.setTypeface(roboto);

        TextView stateTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.state);
        stateTitle.setTypeface(roboto);

        String state = values[i].getState();


        if (state.equals("0")) {
            currentState.setText("Pending");
        } else if (state.equals("1")) {
            currentState.setText("Accepted");
        } else if (state.equals("2")) {
            currentState.setText("Rejected");
        } else if (state.equals("3")) {
            currentState.setText("Track Back");
        }


        check = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.approve);
        check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scaleEffect(v);
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Approved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        cancel = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.trash);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scaleEffect(v);
                swipeLayout.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(150).start();
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return values.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private void scaleEffect(final View view) {

        view.setScaleX(1.5f);
        view.setScaleY(1.5f);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    view.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            view.setScaleX(1f);
                            view.setScaleY(1f);

                        }
                    });

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!!! I've found the solution!

All I had to do was to climb up the view hierarchy - inside the list item I already set a button listener:

```
cancel = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.trash);
cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {}
```

But now that I have the reference for that specific button through the View passed to the onClick - "v", I can ask to get it's parent view. Anyway, the complete code looks like this:

```
cancel = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.trash);
cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        scaleEffect(v);
        LinearLayout a = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
        SwipeLayout parent = (SwipeLayout) a.getParent();
        parent.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(300).start();
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```